# How to make ListView Items Even

Tags: android, listview

I would like my list view items to be lined up and appear as tabular data.  I have four TextViews in each ListItem.  I have the 1st and 4th even on the edges.  I can not get the middle to line up.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
  android:background="@color/row_selector"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
 android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelGas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textColor="#222"
     >
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textColor="#222"
    >
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelApr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="35"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="18dp" >
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelFee"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:text="@+id/label"
   >
</TextView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for all the TextView tags, then the views will have widths exactly according to the weights, regardless of their actual content.

Answer (score 0):

Try using RelativeLayout, it's more powerful and more efficient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:background="@color/row_selector"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelGas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textColor="#222"
     >
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/labelGas"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textColor="#222"
    >
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelApr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/labelDate"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="18dp" >
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelFee"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/labelApr"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@+id/label"
   >
</TextView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ted's right, if you stick with LinearLayout, you can use android:layout_weight="0.25" to each textview, that will make them occupy the same amount of width

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="40dp"
  android:background="@color/row_selector"
  android:paddingLeft="10dp"
  android:paddingRight="5dp"
  android:paddingBottom="10dp"
  android:paddingTop="10dp" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelGas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView1"
    android:textColor="#FFFF00"      >
 </TextView>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView2"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textColor="#ffff0000"    >
 </TextView>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelApr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView3"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textColor="#ff00ff00" >
 </TextView>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelFee"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView4"
    android:textColor="#ffff6666"   >
 </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```